# How to combine multiple nested dictionaries into one

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

If I have n nested dictionaries with different depth of dictionaries with the deepest nested dictionary's value as a list,

For example:

```
{"a":{"b": {"c": {"d": ["ab"]}}}},
{"a" : {"b": {"d": ["aa"]}}}, 
{"a": {"f":{"c":["xx"]}}}, 
{"a":{"b": {"c": {"d": ["ef"]}}}}
```

How can I combine these together to get

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": ["ab","ef"]}}, "d": ["aa"]}, "f":{"c":["xx"]}}}
```

This could be thought out as a tree where `"a"` is the parent of the whole tree and `"b"`, `"f"` are subtrees and so on.

I tried using recursion but I actually have no idea where to start

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [{"a":{"b": {"c": {"d": ["ab"]}}}}, {"a" : {"b": {"d": ["aa"]}}}, {"a": {"f":{"c":["xx"]}}}, {"a":{"b": {"c": {"d": ["ef"]}}}}]
def group(d):
  if all(not isinstance(i, dict) for i in d):
    return [i for b in d for i in b]
  r = [i for b in d for i in b.items()]
  _d = [[a, [c for _, c in b]] for a, b in groupby(sorted(r, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
  return {a:b[0] if len(b) == 1 else group(b) for a, b in _d}

print(group(data))
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': ['ab', 'ef']}, 'd': ['aa']}, 'f': {'c': ['xx']}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each of your dicts contains only one key you don't actually need recursion. It would be more efficient to iteratively obtain the next inner dict until you get a list, at which point you extend the sub-list with the list:

```
l = [
    {"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": ["ab"]}}}},
    {"a": {"b": {"d": ["aa"]}}},
    {"a": {"f": {"c": ["xx"]}}},
    {"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": ["ef"]}}}}
]
o = {}
for d in l:
    n = o
    m = d
    p = None
    while isinstance(m, dict):
        if p is not None:
            if k not in p:
                p[k] = {}
            n = p[k]
        (k, m), = m.items()
        p = n
    p.setdefault(k, []).extend(m)
```

`o` becomes:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': ['ab', 'ef']}, 'd': ['aa']}, 'f': {'c': ['xx']}}}
```